# Can i master reset or fix my android radio?

Tags: electrical, ford, audio, navigation, mondeo

My android radio is'nt working right. Its coming on but not letting me go on any programmes and the radio signal is'nt staying on the chanel i ask for. I want to do a master reset how do i so it. Is there anything i can do. I have tried to reset it button on the front screen.

Comment: is it an "android auto" deck, or one of those super-generic aftermarket android decks?  In other words, did it come with the car new, and if not, how much was it?  A model number would be extremely helpful.  It's possible to factory reset the real ones "usually" (I say that since I only have mine and I know it can be done).

Comment: It came with the car.its says ford when it comes on so im guessing it is a radio that came with the car.i dnt know how to take it out.