# How am i am able to fix or reset a ford android radio

Tags: electrical, ford, audio, mondeo

[image]

I had looked at the fuses and taken the battery out.ive tried thhe factory resef on the setting.but its that bad now i cant even use the touch screen.xx

Comment: A duplicate of : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/62952/10976

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. You're not doing yourself any good in doing so.

Comment: Is it possibl toget some hlep then

Comment: Not unless somebody here knows the answer. This site doesn't work by magic!